# When using a form in Fancybox users cannot enter all entries

Tags: jquery, fancybox

We have a gallery of images and each one triggers a fancybox (iframe) that has details of the image and also an inquiry form. This is part of a dataset so we also have the "next"/"previous" buttons. Problem we find is that when users enter the fields, or they try and check a box, the "previous" action is triggered and the page changes.

We want to have the navigational elements in place, but we also need to allow users to complete the form.

Any help with this would be really appreciated
Thanks

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.5

Comment: Maybe update to fancyBox3